# Reactive form not binding values

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing an API application in net 5 and angular 11. I have reusable component which I use for reactive forms, but am not able to bind values. I have table IStTransaction which has a foreign key stockId from table Stock. I want to purchase a specific stock, and everything works perfectly in template forms. But when I try to use reactive forms, I am able to make a transaction, but two my relevant properties, price and quantity, show value of 0. I am pretty sure the problem is not in my reusable component, since I copied that from one tutorial on Udemy (thanks, Neil:)) and everything works, but I will put it here also. Here is part of my code, please let me know if I should put some more code. Thanks in advance:)

**IStTransaction** - I only use price and quantity, server handles other properties

```
export class IStTransaction {
stockId: number = 0;
price: number = 0;
quantity: number = 0;
purchase: boolean = true;
resolved: number = 0;
```

reusable component **text-input.component.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-text-input',
templateUrl: './text-input.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./text-input.component.scss']
})
export class TextInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
@ViewChild('input', {static: true}) input: ElementRef;
@Input() type = 'text';
@Input() label: string;

constructor(@Self() public controlDir: NgControl) {
this.controlDir.valueAccessor = this;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
const control = this.controlDir.control;
const validators = control.validator ? [control.validator] : [];
const asyncValidators = control.asyncValidator ? [control.asyncValidator] : [];

control.setValidators(validators);
control.setAsyncValidators(asyncValidators);
control.updateValueAndValidity();
}

onChange(event) {
}

onTouched() {
}

writeValue(obj: any): void {
this.input.nativeElement.value = obj || '';
}

registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
this.onChange = fn;
}

registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
this.onTouched = fn;
}
```

**text-input.component.html**

```
<div class="form-label-group">
<input 
    [ngClass]="(controlDir && controlDir.control && controlDir.control.touched) ? 
    !controlDir.control.valid ? 'is-invalid' : 'is-valid' : null"
    [type]="type"
    (input)="onChange($event.target.value)"
    (blur)="onTouched()"
    id="{{label}}" 
    #input
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="{{label}}"
  >

  <label for="{{label}}">{{label}}</label>

 <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="(controlDir && controlDir.control 
 && !controlDir.control.valid && controlDir.control.touched)">
 <span *ngIf="controlDir.control.errors?.required">{{label}} is required</span>
 <span *ngIf="controlDir.control.errors?.pattern">Invalid email address</span>

 </div>

 <div class="invalid-feedback d-block" *ngIf="(controlDir && controlDir.control &&
 !controlDir.control.valid && controlDir.control.dirty)">
    <span *ngIf="controlDir.control.errors?.emailExists">Email address is in use</span>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**add-stock-reactive-form.component.ts** - just the relevant code

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-add-stock-reactive-form',
templateUrl: './add-stock-reactive-form.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./add-stock-reactive-form.component.scss']
})
export class AddStockReactiveFormComponent implements OnInit {
list: FormGroup;
stock: IStock;

ngOnInit(): void {
this.loadStock();
this.createForm();
}

 createForm() {
 this.list= new FormGroup({
 price: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
 quantity: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
 });
 }

onSubmit() {
this.service.formData.stockId = this.stock.id;
this.router.navigateByUrl('myportfolio');
this.service.buyStock1(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(() => {
this.resetForm(this.loginForm);
},
error => {
console.log(error);
});
}
```

**add-stock-reactive-form.component.html**

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
    <div class="col-5">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="{{stock?.symbol}}">
    </div>
    <form [formGroup]="list" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <app-text-input formControlName="price" [label]="'Price'"></app-text-input>
        <app-text-input formControlName="quantity" [label]="'Quantity'"></app-text-input>
       
        <button [disabled]="list.invalid" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" 
  type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. can you create stackblitz?

Comment: first I need to find out what that is:))...sorry for not being informed, programming is my big hobby but I am new to it, started  one year ago

Comment: I see, it's something like code editor, not really sure why I need that in this case?

Comment: ok, now I see what you mean...will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` provider to your custom form control component

```js
@Component({
selector: 'app-text-input',
templateUrl: './text-input.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./text-input.component.scss'],
providers: [
  {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,    // <-- Add to your custom form control component
    multi:true,
    useExisting: TextInputComponent
  }
]
})
export class TextInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
```

**Update**
Tried pulling your custom form control to stackblitz and just fixed a compilation error in text-input.component.html

`(input)="onChange($event.target.value)"` to `(input)="onChange($event.target['value'])"` and seems to be working fine.

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-o2luca?file=src/app/text-input/text-input.component.html)

Comment: tried, doesn't work, the messages in add-stock.html are - no provider for ngcontrol and cannot instantiate cyclic dependency

Comment: I guess this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-o2luca?file=src/app/text-input/text-input.component.html) seems to be working well.

Comment: then what is wrong? strange, I can also use that on another example, but not in this application, maybe I forgot to import everything I should, for example in app.module?

Comment: now i don't understand a thing, it worked, but now it does not work again, quantity and purchase are set to 0 again:(

Comment: I managed to resole everything, the mistake was in my prior code, thank you all for the effort and sorry for taking your time while I made an obvious mistake